# Displaying SQL Server Error Message in c#.net using smo.server class

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I do not have a get error message when I execute `DB.ExecuteNonQuery(Script);`
In the script,  I am inserting

```
create(procedure, table), alter(table), drop(proc, table)
```

command or text file which content procedure, table structure.

I am executing this operation in C# on SQL Server 2008 using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` class

My problem is when some script does not properly means

Example we execute `Create Procedure` statement and get back an error

> procedure already exists in database

This error I want to get in C# code.

How can I solve this problem?

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: seems pretty obvious, once you've run the code once, the procedure already exists in the database. so you would need to drop it before adding it.

Comment: yes , You are right But  i want  to pop up that messsage to UI side this is my problem ....

Comment: above create procedure is example not reality opeartion